# Laravel Ajax display datetime with other format

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, datetime

I have table 'Trip', one of its fields is 'schedule'. The type of 'schedule' is datetime format.
I create a project in laravel. In the Combobox, it displays '2020-04-29 10:09:00', but I want it to be displayed as '29 April 2020'. 
Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thank you.
Here's my code.

OrderController :

```
    public function getTrip(){
        $departure = Input::get('departure_id');
        $destination = Input::get('destination_id');

        $trip_a = Trip::select('schedule')
            ->where(['departure_id' => $departure, 'destination_id' => $destination])
            ->whereDate('schedule', '>', Carbon::now())
            ->get();

        return response()->json($trip_a);
    }
```

In web.php

```
Route::get('/order_trip', 'OrderController@getTrip');
```

In create.blade.php

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <label>Departure From</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="departure_id" id="departure_id">
             <option disabled selected value> -- Departure From -- </option>
                     @foreach($town as $t)
                         <option value="{{ $t->town_id }}">
                                 {{$t->town_name}}
                         </option> 
                     @endforeach 
     </select>
</div>
     @if($errors->has('departure_id'))
         <div class="text-danger">
              {{ $errors->first('departure_id')}}
         </div>
     @endif

<div class="col-sm-6">
     <label>Destination</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="destination_id" id="destination_id">
             <option disabled selected value> -- Destination -- </option>
                     @foreach($town as $t)
                         <option value="{{ $t->town_id }}">
                                 {{$t->town_name}}
                         </option> 
                     @endforeach 
     </select>
</div>
     @if($errors->has('destination_id'))
         <div class="text-danger">
              {{ $errors->first('destination_id')}}
         </div>
     @endif                          

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>Date</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="day" id="day">
                <option disabled selected value> -- Date -- </option>
           </select>
     </div>
         @if($errors->has('day'))
               <div class="text-danger">
                    {{ $errors->first('day')}}
               </div>
         @endif
```

Ajax

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#day').click(function(){
        var selected_departure = $('#departure_id').val();
        var selected_destination = $('#destination_id').val();

        $.get('/order_trip?departure_id=' +selected_departure+'&destination_id=' 
          +selected_destination, function(data){
              $('#day').empty();
              $.each(data, function(index, value){
                console.log(value.schedule);
                $('#day').append('<option 
                   value='+value.schedule+'>'+value.schedule+'</option>');
              });
        });  
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an accessor to format your date. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
public function getScheduleAttribute($value)
{
   return $value->format('d F Y');
}
```

### Update

And don't forget to cast your field to date time [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

```
protected $casts = [
        'schedule' => 'datetime',
    ];
```

And if needed set a mutator [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

```
public function setScheduleAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['schedule'] = Carbon::parse($value);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But where should I write these codes? I am sorry, I am still learning

Comment: Into the model -> Trip.php

Comment: Error "Call to a member function format() on string "

Comment: Did you add the $casts?

Comment: Yes, I did add the $casts

Comment: My bad, please change the accessor to: public function getScheduleAttribute($value)
{
   return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d F Y');
}